# Weird Common lisp SBCL *query-io* behavior

Tags: linux, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Currently learning Common Lisp with SBCL, and it's bugging me how *query-io* has some unexpected differences from standard input and output. I will assume that *standard-output* contains a newline, or is formatted with one, because

`(format *query-io* "hello")`

Contains no newline at all.

Now, using read-line gives me this behavior

```
(defun read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (read-line))
```

```
(read "message")
> hello
"hello"
message: NIL
```

I was told this is expected, as SBCL would wait for a newline to be inputted before printing the format, but what I don't get is the result of changing the second line

```
(defun read (prompt)
  (format *standard-output* "~a: " prompt)
  (read-line))
```

```
(read "message")
> hello
message: 
"hello"
NIL
```

Why is the order different? I don't think the newline after the prompt variable affects the result

Comment: READ is already a standard Lisp function. Are you replacing that? Not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want things to behave in a predictable way you should write programs which ensure that:

- don't name the function `read` (in fact I'm extremely convinced that SBCL wouldn't have allowed you to name the function `read`, unless perhaps you are using a prehistoric version);
- be clear about what streams you are actually reading and writing to;
- if you want output to appear at a given time, say you do.

So in your first function you are doing something equivalent to what I assume is this:

```
(defun f1 (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (read-line))
```

This:

1. writes the prompt to `*query-io*`, which means that at some future time it may appear on whatever `*query-io*` points at;
2. reads a line from `*standard-input*`;
3. returns the result of reading that line.

So if you call this function it will read a line from `*standard-input*` which perhaps is the terminal but may not be.  At some time after the call to `format` some output probably will appear on `*query-io*` which may also point at the terminal.  There is no guarantee as to when or in fact even *if* that output will appear: for instance if you modify the function to be:

```
(defun f1.1 (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (clear-output *query-io*)
  (read-line))
```

it is quite possible that the prompt will *never* appear.

When output actually appears from functions which write to streams if you don't explicitly say 'write it now' depends on many, many factors:

- what the stream points to;
- if there's a buffer;
- how big the buffer is;
- how full the buffer is;
- whether you later called `clear-output` on the stream and whether `clear-output` actually does anything;
- whether you later closed the stream with `:abort t` and whether *that* actually does anything;
- the price of chocolate on the moons of Jupiter.

In your second function things are mostly the same:

```
(defun f2 (prompt)
  (format *standard-output* "~a: " prompt)
  (read-line))
```

This time `format` is writing to `*standard-output*`, not `*query-io*` and again you are reading a line from `*standard-input*`.  And again, when and if the output from `format` appears is in the lap of the gods.

So what you need to do is

- be clear about what streams you are using;
- actually ask for output to appear when you want it, not later.

In particular *never* make assumptions that output written to some stream appears at any given point 'on its own' or 'after a newline', or anything like that.

If you want to prompt and read from `*query-io*` you do it like this:

```
(defun f3 (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (finish-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
```

If you want to prompt on `*standard-output*` and read from `*standard-input*` then:

```
(defun f4 (prompt)
  (format *standard-output* "~a: " prompt)
  (finish-output *standard-output*)
  (read-line *standard-input*))
```

In this last case you can actually leave out the streams (and use `t` for `format`) because they are the defaults: still it is probably better to be explicit.

`f3` is probably better, since prompting and reading is what `*query-io*` is for.

Comment: I wrote READ in my question but not in the actual code, big mistake since I didn't know it was a reserved name. About the rest, really thank you man, it's all more clear to me now